# How can i create buttons based on the number of objects in my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, button, foreach

I have an array with 3 objects

```
map.la = [object, object, object];
```

I want to create a button for each of these objects. The reason i have to dybamicaly create the buttons is because the number of objects
varies from time to time.

How can i loop through each object and create a button for it and then set the tooltip of the button to equal the name property inside each object?

the button:

```
this._selectionbutt = new SegButton({
    items: [

        //each of the below items (this.selection) should be added here to items array. because we have 3 buttons there
        //should be three unique items here. the items should have the same name as the variable we instantiate the
        //button with.

        this._oSelection
    ]
});

this.selection = new SegButtItems({
    icon: "map",
    tooltip: //this should be the name property of each item
    press: this._handleSelection();
});
```

Once the user selects the button any of the buttons they will be taken to the same function (this._handleSelection()) and this function
will need to check the name property string e.g. "map333" and thats it.

Any guidance will be highly appreicated :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

HTML code. Create div, to wich we will add buttons

```
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

Js code:

```
//create objects

var Object1 = {
    icon: "map",
    tooltip: "Press Me",
    press: 'console.log("Button1 pressed")'
};
var Object2 = {
    icon: "map",
    tooltip: "Press Me",
    press: 'console.log("Button2 pressed")'
};
var Object3 = {
    icon: "map",
    tooltip: "Press Me",
    press: 'console.log("Button3 pressed")'
};

//add objects to array
var ar = [Object1, Object2, Object3];
//add buttons for every object in array
ar.forEach( function(v) { 
    var button= document.createElement('button');
    button.type= 'button';
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v.tooltip));
    button.setAttribute('onClick',v.press);
  document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(button);
 } );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it must be all javascript and it must use the "this._selectionbutt" described above.